# Way to get signed value from unsigned and vice versa

Tags: c#, converters

So...
For example i have some number like `9ecd` which one is `40653`
BUT i want to use it like signed `-24883`.
So, is there any way to do it without "sing bit"-workaround by ">>15" (sic!) if i even cant use it at declaration at this point

UPD: It was all sunny and such with Oded answer, but then i tried to use the same trick on sbyte.

Comment: `unchecked((short)0x9ecd)`

Comment: Although you should only need `unchecked` if you explicitly turned on `checked` somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy,

```
int u = 0x9ecd;
int i = (short)u;
```

`i` will be `-24883`